# What is a 'rollback'?

Tags: support

[Cleanup](https://ell.stackexchange.com/badges/4/cleanup) is a badge that requires you to do/have a *rollback*.
What is it and how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the revision history of a post you can see the different revisions. You can rollback to a specific revision if you want to undo a change in the post.

[image: Rollback]

To see the revision history you first must have a post that was changed after a 5 minute grace period. Then you can click on the *edited xxx ago* or *edited xxx* button to see the revisions.

[image: Revision History]